# Live graphing multiple channels of data, platform / framework selection

Tags: linux, monitoring, serial-communication, graph-drawing

What framework / library / platform would you suggest for creating a Linux, preferably multiplatform, application displaying eight oscilloscope like graphs, updating in realtime? I'm imagining a view of the eight channels scrolling steadily to the left, with the newest data coming in on the right.

The data source is a microcontroller device I'm developing right now, which AD converts the 8 channels and blasts all measurements to the PC by an USB virtual com port, I'm thinking in the order of 100 samples/sec. I can brew my own protocol for this data transfer, but again, is there some standard out there I should use to get compatibility and not reinvent the wheel?

(this is a hobby project for monitoring whats going on in my car's non-OBD motorcontroller)

Thanks,
Lars

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) package in a couple of projects.  It is a very powerful and flexible tool and is free and open source.